# Using Data.Map in monadic context

Tags: haskell, dictionary, monads

A map that I am operating on has monadic keys (of type `IO Double`). I need to use `findMax` on this map. Can I use `liftM` for this?

```
Map.findMax $ Map.fromList [(f x, "X"), (f y, "Y"), (f z, "Z")]
```

Here `f x` has type `IO Double`.

Comment: You can't have a map with `IO a` keys (for any *a*), because there is no Ord instance for them. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I needed a key-value map where the keys are calculated by using an external function f(x) which has a monadic return type. I could map X to f(x) and Y to f(y) and so on but I need to find the maximum of all f-values, and since findmax operates on keys, I decided to make f's the keys and the labels as values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense to have `IO`-typed values as keys in a map. A value of type `IO t` for some type `t` can be thought of as a "program" that produces a value of type `t` each time it is run: you can run it multiple times and every time it may produce a different value.

So, want you probably want is to first run the "program" to obtain some results; these results then can be the keys of your map.

For example, if you have a "program"

```
f :: Int -> IO Int
```

that takes integers and computes, potentially effectfully, integers, and you need to run in on inputs from `[1 .. 10]` to obtain the keys of your map, you could proceed as follows:

```
createMap :: IO (Map Int Int)
createMap = do
  keys <- mapM f [1 .. 10]
  return $ foldr (\k -> Map.insert k (g k)) Map.empty keys
```

This assumes that the values are computed from the keys by a function

```
g :: Int -> Int
```

`createMap` produces a map from integers to integers; it returns it in the `IO`-monad, because which keys are used to populate the map is possibly subject to the environment in which the "program" `f` was run.

### Your Problem

In your situation, this means that the maximal value you want to compute, has to be produced in the `IO`-monad as well:

```
getMax :: Int -> Int -> Int -> IO (Double, String)
getMax x y z = do
  keys <- mapM f [x, y, z]
  let entries = zip keys ["X", "Y", "Z"]
  return (Map.findMax (Map.fromList entries))
```

### Constructing the map incrementally

The map of course does not need to be created in one go, but can also be constructed incrementally:

```
f :: Int -> IO Int
f = ...

g :: Int -> Int
g = ...

createMap :: IO (Map Int Int)
createMap = do
  -- create the empty map
  let m0 = Map.empty

  -- insert an entry into the map
  k1 <- f 1
  let m1 = Map.insert k1 (g k1) m0

  -- extend the map with another entry
  k2 <- f 2
  let m2 = Map.insert k2 (g k2) m1

  -- return the map
  return m2
```

Comment: +1 for the program explanation, but I note that of course `createMap`-style solutions only work if you create the Map all at once rather than incrementally.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to create the map incrementally? (I've added an example to my answer.)

Comment: Well, `createMap` is one-shot; you can't add later data to the map in response to program input, changing state, etc. However, I've sent an edit in that shows how to abstracts the insertion out into `insertNew` (like my `insertValue`), which should hopefully make it clear how to achieve this.

Comment: I don't agree: you can actually add data to the map later on. Why not?

Comment: Yes, of course. I was just saying that your *original* `createMap` didn't show how to add values to the map later on with the keys being produced by a monadic action. Admittedly, this is more a question of understanding how to structure monadic code than it is of Maps.

Answer (score 5):

You should execute the monadic action before inserting into the map, like this:

```
insertValue :: Value -> Map Key Value -> IO (Map Key Value)
insertValue value m = do
  key <- calculateKey value
  return $ Map.insert key value m
```

where

```
calculateKey :: Value -> IO Key
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand. What is the type of the second argument? The function that defines the key doesn't take vale as a parameter. The values are simply strings assigned as labels (to display a meaningful string instead of/along with the double quantity in the key if it is the maximum)

Comment: To `insertValue`? It's the map you're inserting into, a `Map Key Value` — obviously, substitute your actual key and value types.

Comment: Basically, you should replace `process (Map.insert (calculateKey value) value m)` with `insertValue value m >>= process`, or `do { let m' = Map.insert (calculateKey value) m; ... }` with `do { m' <- insertValue value m; ... }`, etc.

Comment: I am still not sure about how the types work out. As per your function calculateKey takes a IO Map type argument.So my insertValue is essentially {insertValue value m x = do
                                       key <- <$>f(x)
                                       return $ Map.insert key value }

Comment: No. calculateKey takes only a `Value` argument, and produces an `IO Key` monadic action that, when executed, returns a value of type `Key`. I'm not sure what your code example means; `key <- <$>f(x)` isn't valid syntax.

Comment: That's what I don't understand. My calculateKey method does NOT take Value argument. It is calculated based on an external function which returns monadic (IO Double) value.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6006/discussion-between-atlantis-and-ehird)

Comment: I sent an edit in to dblhelix's answer to explain a bit more before seeing this; if they're accepted and clarify things for you, hopefully we won't need to :) I'll wait to see what you think.