# Haskell: Filtering through a dictionary/hash/map with IO() values

Tags: haskell

I have a function which signature is String -> String -> IO (Maybe String)
Now, I use this function to build values for a dictionary and I end up with: [(String,IO (Maybe String))]

I have to analyze the values in the dictionary and based on the result return the appropriate key. I was hoping to just use filter on the Map to step through it but I can't think of a way to extract that IO action on the fly. So how do I map/filter through the dictionary running the IO action and based on the result of the  IO action's value return appropriate key of the dictionary?? Is there an easy way of doing it or I just got myself in a mess?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Data.Map in monadic context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575317/using-data-map-in-monadic-context)

Comment: If I understand this correctly, your problem is that you don't actually want the map to contain `IO` actions, but rather the results of running them. So the problem is not how to filter a map containing IO actions, but rather how to build the map containing the results of those IO actions. If you want help with that, we'll need to see the code that builds the map.

Comment: @hammar Thanks for the reply but I think the code that generated the map is not relevant as I could simply start the question with "Given a Map with signature [(String,IO (Maybe String))] ... blah blah" yes, you understand correctly. I need to filter the map based on the results of the IO actions which are the values of the map. So something like that in pseudo code: superFilter (\x -> ioResultOf x /= Nothing && == "01") theMap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the solution is to use `sequence` with something like

```
sequence . map (\(a,mb) -> (mb >>= \b -> return (a,b)))
```

then you can simply use `liftM` to apply your filter to the resulting `IO [(String,Maybe String)]`.

`liftM` is in Control.Monad.  Alternatively, in do notation

```
myFilter :: (String,(Maybe String)) -> Bool) 
            -> [(String,IO (Maybe String))] 
            -> IO [(String,(Maybe String))]
myFilter f ml =
   do
       l <- sequence . map (\(a,mb) -> (mb >>= \b -> return (a,b))) $ ml
       return $ filter f ml
```

Perhaps some refactoring is in order.  Often when working with monads you want to use `mapM` instead of `map`.

There is also a `filterM` function in Control.Monad.  It might be what you need.

---

Edit: it was pointed out in comments that

```
sequence . map (\(a,mb) -> (mb >>= \b -> return (a,b))) $ ml
```

is equivalent to

```
mapM (\(a,mb) -> fmap ((,) a) mb) ml
```

so

```
myFiter' f = (liftM $ filter f) .  mapM (\(a,mb) -> fmap ((,) a) mb)
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this and report ... :)

Comment: `mapM f = sequence . map f`, and `foo >>= return . bar = fmap bar foo`; therefore I'd recommend `l <- mapM (\(a,mb) -> fmap ((,) a) mb) ml`. You could actually write that lambda as `(uncurry $ fmap . (,))` but that's starting to get obscure.

Comment: Using `Data.Traversable`'s generalization of sequence, if [`(,) o` was already an instance of `Traversable`](http://haskell.1045720.n5.nabble.com/Traversable-instance-for-o-td5118254.html), you could use `f :: [(String, IO (Maybe String))] -> IO [(String, Maybe String)] ; f = mapM sequence`.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a function which signature is `String -> String -> IO (Maybe String)` Now, I use this function to build values for a dictionary and I end up with: `[(String,IO (Maybe String))]`

This part doesn't add up for me. How do you input only 2 strings, and end up with a meaningful result of type `[(String, IO (Maybe String))]`?

Lacking the particulars, lets assume your situation is something like this:

```
f :: String -> String -> IO (Maybe String)
magic :: String -> (String, String)
```

`magic` takes some key, and somehow splits the key into the two input strings needed by `f`. So, assuming you have a list of keys, you would wind up with a `[(String, IO (Maybe String))]` like this:

```
-- ks :: [String]
myMap = map (\k -> let (a,b) = magic k in (k, f a b)) ks
```

But...wouldn't it be so much nicer if we had a `[(String, Maybe String)]` instead? Assuming we're inside an IO action...

```
someIOAction = do
  ...
  myMap <- monadicMagicks (\k -> let (a,b) = magic k in (k, f a b)) ks
```

But what `monadicMagicks` could we use to make this work out right? Let's look at the types that we expect from these expressions

```
monadicMagicks (\k -> ...) ks             :: IO [(String, Maybe String)]
(\k -> let (a,b) = magic k in (k, f a b)) :: String -> (String, IO (Maybe String))
ks                                        :: [String]

-- therefore
monadicMagicks :: (String -> (String, IO (Maybe String)))
               -> [String]
               -> IO [(String, Maybe String)]
```

Stop...Hoogle time. Let's generalize what we're looking for a bit, first. We have two basic data types here: `String`, which appears to be the "input", and `Maybe String`, which appears to be the "output". So let's replace `String` with `a` and `Maybe String` with `b`. So we're looking for [`(a -> (a, IO b)) -> [a] -> IO [(a, b)]`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+%28a%2C+IO+b%29%29+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+IO+%5B%28a%2C+b%29%5D). Hrm. No results found. Well, if we could get a result type of just `IO [b]`, then in a do block we could get it out of IO, and then `zip` it with the original key list. That also means the function we put in wouldn't have to perform the pairing of key with result. So let's simplify what we're looking for and try again: [`(a -> IO b) -> [a] -> IO [b]`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+IO+b%29+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+IO+%5Bb%5D). Hey, check it out! `mapM` matches that type signature perfectly.

```
monadicMagicks :: (a -> IO b) -> [a] -> IO [(a, b)]
monadicMagicks f xs = do
  ys <- mapM f xs
  return $ zip xs ys
```

This could actually be written more succinctly, and with a more general type signature:

```
monadicMagicks :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [(a, b)]
monadicMagicks f xs = zip xs `liftM` mapM f xs

someIOAction = do
  ...
  -- Like we said, the lambda no longer has to pair up the key with the result
  myMap <- monadicMagicks (\k -> let (a,b) = magic k in f a b) ks
```

This last line could also be rewritten a bit shorter, if you're comfortable with function composition:

```
  myMap <- monadicMagicks (uncurry f . magic) ks
```

Note that `monadicMagicks` might not make much sense for some monads, which is probably why it isn't in the standard libs. (For example, using `mapM` in the list monad usually means that the result will have a different length than the input):

```
ghci> mapM (\x -> [x, -x]) [1,2]
[[1,2],[1,-2],[-1,2],[-1,-2]]
```